# TypeDoc: How to make props of react component display/list in on the same page as component doc?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typedoc

```
/**
  * Interface of props of the Component
  */
export interface ComponentProps {
  /**
   * Name of sth
   */
  name: string,
  /**
   * happening on click component
   */
  onClick: () => void
}

/**
 * @category Component
 */
export function Component({ name, onClick }: ComponentProps) {
  (...)
}
```

When I'm generating docs via typedoc I got two pages:

1. `Component` page with props represented as `__namedParameters: ComponentProps` (where `ComponentProps` are linked, which it's ok)
2. `ComponentProps` page with list of types and name

Can I somehow make to show/list props with types on `Component` page?